# Phonegap 3.5 fetching audio / video files from external sd card Android

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Currently I am not able to fetch video (.mp4) and audio (.wav) files from external sd card, basically I want to fetch the files and convert them to base64 and send them to the server.

Here is my code

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

 // fileSystem's root is -> file:///storage/emulated/0/

  var url = "cdvfile://localhost/root/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20141018_143740.mp4";

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(url, function(fileObj) {

     var fullPath = fileObj.fullPath;

     // fullPath -> file:/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20141018_143740.mp4

     fileSystem.root.getFile(fullPath, null, function(fileEntry) {

       fileEntry.file(function(file) {

        //.. FileReader function to convert the file to base64 by reader.readAsDataURL(file)

       },errorFunc);


     },errorFunc);

  },errorFunc);
},errorFunc);
```

Now the problem is I am not able to get the .mp4 file i.e. my fileSystem.root.getFile is giving me the error
Error code 1 i.e. File Not Found

After checking few stack overflow questions and http://rickluna.com/wp/2014/01/accessing-external-storage-in-android-phonegap-3-3/ blog I think my problem lies in "root"

i.e. my fileSystem obj (success callback of requestFileSystem method) looks like this:

```
filesystem: FileSystem
fullPath: "/"
isDirectory: true
isFile: false
name: ""
nativeURL: "file:///storage/emulated/0/"
__proto__: utils.extend.F
```

So is it possible to change the root? i.e.  from **file:///storage/emulated/0/** to **file:///storage/** so that I can call getFile and pass the absolute url i.e. /extSdCard/DCIM when( file:///storage/) becomes root

I even tried by changing root i.e.

fileSystem.root.fullPath = 'file:///storage/';

even I tried to change the nativeURL property of fileSystem object but it's not working

ps. solution given in the blog hasn't worked for me

ps ps. The same code is working fine when my absolute url is:      file:///storage/emulated/0/MRS/fileName.txt
and I am passing the relative url in function i.e. fileSystem.root.getFile("MRS/fileName.txt",...)